# Installing Apache, PHP, MySQL on Windows 8.1 - Apache won't start - Requested operation has failed

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, wamp

I am having trouble installing a home personal LAMP development server in Windows 8.1.

I tried to manually install Apache, MySQL, and PHP on Windows 8.1. It appears that both Apache and MySQL installed correctly because I can do "select databases" in MySQL, and localhost said something to the effect of "If you are seeing this message it means Apache installed correctly".

When I try to start the Apache2 service it says:

> The requested operation has failed.

But, the service started after I installed it just fine. Only after a reboot did it start giving me this error and refusing to start.

I wonder why this so troublesome? I followed the instructions perfectly but it didn't give me the results that I was told to expect.

## Specifications

> #### OPERATING SYSTEM:
>
> Windows 8.1 64-bit
>
> #### APACHE SERVER:
>
> httpd-2.0.65-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi
>
> #### MYSQL SERVER:
>
> mysql-installer-community-5.6.19.0.msi
>
> #### PHP for Windows:
>
> php-5.3.28-Win32-VC9-x86.msi
> VC9 x86 Thread Safe (2013-Dec-12 01:59:01)

## Some final notes

- IIS is not installed on this machine.
- Firewall is disabled as 3dmasters recommends
- I'm not an Apache expert, which is why on a previous system I used WAMP, but I remember when I installed it in 2009, even with a turnkey "package" that was supposed to eliminate problems, I still had problems of compatibility and configuration after the install. I eventually had success with WAMP and used it for learning PHP.
- I am aware that there are pre-made packages like XAMPP and WAMP, but I don't want to use them this time, unless somebody can tell me *unequivocally* that there is absolutely no way even a seasoned programmer/computer specialist/network administrator can manually install Apache/MySQL/PHP on Windows 8.1.
- In 3dmasters' tutorial video he is using VirtualBox and the no-ssl version of Apache. Again, his tutorial seems great and perhaps others were able to get up and running the first time with his instructions. However, I followed his instructions fairly close and it didn't work for me. It may be useful to note that Both of the sources (the most recent I could find) I used for the install were published last summer (2013). In McMillian's article, he summarizes the various concurrent problems that may be causing the "The requested operation has failed" error:

> "The problem seems to by [sic] that there are numerous versions of Apache
> and PHP.  Most combinations of them are incompatible with each other.
> Support does not seem to have been kept remotely up to date and the
> documentation is terrible.  Vital information is missing and in places
> it seems to be inaccurate.  This paper describes what worked mid
> 2013."

Thus, there were conflicts that at least one person knew about and was able to articulate and write about it. Yet I have found no other resources that address this in a step-by-step "this is what you should do, and this is why" along with, "don't do this because" manner. The closest admonishment of that sort was to make sure you are installing "thread safe" versions of the software, which I am.

## Sources

> **Installing Apache 2.2.22, Php 5.3.26 and Mysql 5.6.12 Microsoft**
> Publisher: 3dmasters
> Published: Jun 28, 2013
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKbEzmMliNM
>
> **Installing Apache and PHP on Windows**
> Author: John McMillan
> Published: July 25, 2013
> http://johnrmcmillan.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/installing-apache-and-php-on-windows./

Comment: What was the port number you used?

Comment: Port number wasn't part of of the tutorial so I guess the best I can say is I didn't change any port number assignments.

Comment: You should try this question over at our neighbors: http://serverfault.com

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. The reason I posted it here is that I wasn't sure, and it is by no means clear to me, that it is Apache that was the problem. I don't know if PHP or MySQL or Windows is the issue. Given my clarification, do you still think this should be migrated to ServerFault? In otherwords, are you fairly certain that APACHE IS the problem? If so, I will be happy to migrate it if you can tell me how. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an Apache 2.0 VC6 build with a PHP 5.3 VC9 build. Those builds have to at least match; you can't have Apache VC6 load a PHP VC9 module/extension. And I'm not even sure if Apache 2.0 can load PHP5 above 5.2 at all.

Is there a reason for these older versions?

> But, the service started after I installed it just fine. Only after a reboot did it start giving me this error and refusing to start

Open the command line in Admin mode (right click cmd.exe, select Run as admin) and execute:

```
httpd -t
httpd -k start
```

It will output the problem.

If it says something about not being able to bind to port 80, check for the Services outlined in this guide:

[Opening Up Port 80 For Apache to Use On Windows](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/opening-up-port-80-for-apache-to-use-on-windows)

> unless somebody can tell me unequivocally that there is absolutely no way even a seasoned programmer/computer specialist/network administrator can manually install Apache/MySQL/PHP on Windows 8.1

It will take at least a few days to a few weeks if you really want to get it working fully, and correct for all edge-cases. Otherwise you should check out Xampp, WampServer, WampDeveloper Pro (not free), EasyPHP.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. "It will take at least a few days to a few weeks if you really want to get it working fully, and correct for all edge-cases." Based on that, I will be uninstalling apache mysql and php then installing WampServer. Are there any tips you would give or gotchas I should be aware of (i.e., Is uninstalling all these not as intutive as it seems? Like how Norton/Symantec antivirus, in the old days, would never fully uninstall ... not fully cleaning up after itself). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the binaries from apache.org with the latest PHP builds. They use different CRT, furthermore - apache.org still uses VC6 and that is legacy. You can fetch a newer apache build from http://www.apachelounge.com/ and the corresponding PHP from http://windows.php.net/ . Be sure that the builds use the same CRT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know what "CRT" is. I thought that was a computer monitor type. Can you clarify?

Comment: CRT - C runtime. Effectively - the visual studio version it was compiled with. Currently PHP prior to 5.5 is compiled with VC9, from 5.5 on with VC11. That means you should use an Apache build compiled with the same Visual Studio version as PHP.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try your suggestion and report back.